# How to detect the event that trigger the camera of an andoird phone

Tags: android, android-studio, architecture, operating-system

I would like to extract the log of the event that happen when in my Android phone an application require the use of the camera.
The goal is, for example, capture the log (from a pc application or from an app)when i open my camera and i shot a photo.
I try to find out some application over the web but with bad results

essentially i would like to monitor the events of my phone, and in particular when an application request the use of the camera.
When i shot a photo with istagram for example i would like to capture that event

i hope that i was clear

All the type of help is regarded

Comment: Perhaps I am missing understanding but are you looking to output text to the debugger when you take a photo? You can use -    Log.e("CameraActivity","Here is my output log");   - Otherwise can you explain better what "capture the log" means?

Comment: ok, my goal is capture the log of all the application of the system.
Not the application that i personally built, but the application like istagram or when i open the camera.
essentially i would like to monitor the event of my phone, and in particular when an application request the use of the camera. (i'm going to edit the original question)

Answer (score 0):

This is my best advice for a solution though I think a better answer could come along.

Here is a piece on debugging other Android apps if you are just wanting to know for your own personal use. Then this solution will work for you..
[Debugging 3rd Party Android Apps](https://kov4l3nko.github.io/blog/2018-01-20-debugging-thirdparty-android-java-code/)

I think your next best direction is to search Github for source code for a similar concept and learn from there. Here is code for performance monitoring - [Mobile App Performance](https://github.com/zhaobao/AppsMonitor)
Here is a library for In App Dev Tools that might be able to cover other apps - [InAppDevTools](https://github.com/rafaco/InAppDevTools)

From there I recommend doing some digging and learning from their code to find out the limitations of debugging 3rd party apps. What your asking maybe be somewhat impossible if I understand correctly, just because Instagram might not be outputting logs, and Android might limit the information an app can give out.

Comment: i start to find out a lot of persons think that this is impossible, especially in the latest devices.
however thanks, i'll try with your tips